# SSRS Report drop down parameters. Use SP or embeded SQL query for datasource?

Tags: ssrs, visual-studio

When I create SSRS reports I create stored procedures to bring data into my report. When I create the report parameters I just embed SQL code directly in to the parameter/SSRS report.

**Should I also create stored procedures for my parameter data sources?**

It seems like a bit of overkill to create a SP for every single paramamter/datasource in a report but I guess if you want to be able to modify the SQL code the parameter uses to load the drop down values without having to open the actual report, then I would probably want to go with SPs for everything....

Comment: I think you answered your own question...it is up to the designer and the standard you want to use when building your reports.

Comment: I was wondering more if there was an existing generally accepted standard or best practices way of  populating the values of a dropdown parameter in SSRS (SP vs embedded query). Pros and Cons of using 1 method vs the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is not a set (or recommended) standard (that I could find). Since development needs vary from project to project the developer should decide during the development process, whether to create stored procedures for their parameter data sources or to simply hard code the drop down values inside the report itself.